# How to display current user details in new window in php

Tags: php

I have created register form using php mqsql.

After registered that particular user details need to retrieve from database and show in new window.

This is my below:

index.php:

```
<?php
    define('INCLUDE_CHECK',1);
    require "config.php";
    require "functions.php";
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Creating a Facebook-like Registration Form with jQuery</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="demo.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="div-regForm">
<div class="form-title">Sign Up</div>
<div class="form-sub-title">It's free and anyone can join</div>
<form id="regForm" action="submit.php" method="post">
<table>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td><label for="fname">First Name:</label></td>
    <td><div class="input-container"><input name="fname" id="fname" type="text" /></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label for="lname">Last Name:</label></td>
    <td><div class="input-container"><input name="lname" id="lname" type="text" /></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label for="email">Your Email:</label></td>
    <td><div class="input-container"><input name="email" id="email" type="text" /></div></td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label for="pass">New Password:</label></td>
    <td><div class="input-container"><input name="pass" id="pass" type="password" /></div></td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <td><label for="pass">Phone Number:</label></td>
    <td><div class="input-container"><input name="phone" id="phone" type="text" /></div></td>
  </tr>
    <td><label for="sex-select">I am:</label></td>
    <td>
    <div class="input-container">
    <select name="sex_select" id="sex-select">
    <option value="0">Select Sex:</option>
    <option value="1">Female</option>
    <option value="2">Male</option>
    </select>
    </div>   
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label>Birthday:</label></td>
    <td>
    <div class="input-container">
    <select name="month"><option value="0">Month:</option><?=generate_options(1,12)?></select>
    <select name="day"><option value="0">Day:</option><?=generate_options(1,31)?></select>
    <select name="year"><option value="0">Year:</option><?=generate_options(date('Y'),1900)?></select>
    </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td><input type="submit" class="greenButton" value="Sign Up" /><img id="loading" src="img/ajax-loader.gif" alt="working.." />
</td>
  </tr> 
  </tbody>
</table>
</form>
<div id="error">
&nbsp;
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

code_exec.php:

```
    <?php
       include 'config.php';
        error_reporting(E_ERROR);
        session_start();
        $fname=$_POST['fname'];
        $lname=$_POST['lname'];
        $email=$_POST['email'];
        $pass=$_POST['pass'];
        $phone=$_POST['phone'];
        $sex_select=$_POST['sex_select'];
        $month=$_POST['month'];
        $day=$_POST['day'];
        $year=$_POST['year'];

        $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO crop(fname, lname, email, pass, phone,`sex_select`, month,day,year)  
VALUES ('$fname', '$lname', '$email', '$pass','$phone','$sex_select', '$month','$day','$year')");
printf("Last inserted record has id %d\n", mysql_insert_id()); // This will print the last insert id 
if (!$result) {
    die(msg(0,"wrong query"));
}
elseif(mysql_insert_id())
{

$_SESSION["fname"] = $fname;
$_SESSION["lname"] =  $lname;
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $pass=$_POST['pass'];
    $phone=$_POST['phone'];
    $sex_select=$_POST['sex_select'];
    $month=$_POST['month'];
    $day=$_POST['day'];
    $year=$_POST['year'];

}
    ?>
```

and this is submit.php:

```
<?php
// we check if everything is filled in
    require "config.php";
    require "functions.php";

if(empty($_POST['fname']) || empty($_POST['lname']) || empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['pass']) || empty($_POST['sex_select']) || empty($_POST['phone']) || empty($_POST['month']) || empty($_POST['day']) || empty($_POST['year']))
{
    die(msg(0,"All the fields are required"));
}


// is the sex selected?

if(!(int)$_POST['sex_select'])
{
    die(msg(0,"You have to select your sex"));
}


// is the birthday selected?

if(!(int)$_POST['day'] || !(int)$_POST['month'] || !(int)$_POST['year'])
{
    die(msg(0,"You have to fill in your birthday"));
}


// is the email valid?

if(!(preg_match("/^[\.A-z0-9_\-\+]+[@][A-z0-9_\-]+([.][A-z0-9_\-]+)+[A-z]{1,4}$/", $_POST['email'])))
    die(msg(0,"You haven't provided a valid email"));

// is the phone number valid?

if(!(preg_match("/([0-9]{10})|([0-9]{3}\\s+[0-9]{3}\\s+[0-9]{4})/", $_POST['phone'])))
die(msg(0,"You haven't provided a valid phone number"));

// Here you must put your code for validating and escaping all the input data,
// inserting new records in your DB and echo-ing a message of the type:

// echo msg(1,"/member-area.php");

include 'code_exec.php';

// where member-area.php is the address on your site where registered users are
// redirected after registration.
echo msg(1,"registered.html");


?>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you try so far and what problems you encountered ?

Comment: From session get the user id and fetch the data from database

Comment: I already used session and didn't get it, so removed from my code. can you please show me exact code @Cakephp.Saint. please see my updated post

Comment: Post your problem clearly. For example I logged using login.php file. After login it will redirect to profile.php. So After login in profile.php var_dump($_SESSION) and check that has the user data or not. If you not set the session after successful login then nothing will come

Comment: After Insert query use SELECT query get the value and set in SESSION. Access that SESSION where ever u want

Comment: ok @Cakephp.Saint: for that how can i add code ?

Comment: can you please show me with code @Cakephp.Saint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    include 'config.php';
    error_reporting(E_ERROR);
    session_start();
    $fname=$_POST['fname'];
    $lname=$_POST['lname'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $pass=$_POST['pass'];
    $phone=$_POST['phone'];
    $sex_select=$_POST['sex_select'];
    $month=$_POST['month'];
    $day=$_POST['day'];
    $year=$_POST['year'];

    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO crop(fname, lname, email, pass, phone,`sex_select`, month,day,year) , VALUES ('$fname', '$lname', '$email', '$pass','$phone','$sex_select', '$month','$day','$year')");

printf("Last inserted record has id %d\n", mysql_insert_id()); // This will print the last insert id 

if (!$result) {
    die(msg(0,"wrong query"));
}
elseif(mysql_insert_id())
{

$_SESSION["fname"] = $fname;
$_SESSION["lname"] =  $lname;
....

}
```

Comment: Hi @user4119973 Here we can give basic idea. We cant sit and write the code for you specially for basic items. Please learn basic from w3schools.com and try

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if you are using mysqli, or mysql :-) but how i understand your problem you can you "$yourdatabaseconnnection->insert_id", this will return the last "id", inserted in your [UserDatabase] database, from the connection the user uses. Then send that with a $_GET[], or an session to the next page :-)

Comment: this is like answer?

Answer (score 0):

use target="_blank" so that it opens in a new window

```
<form id="regForm" target="_blank" action="submit.php" method="post">
```

make sure u start the session in each and every page using

```
if(!session_id())
     session_start();
```

then save users details in a session after the successful insertion in to the database
(i.e)

```
$_SESSION['user_id']=""//some value;
```

then **redirect** your submit.php to a nother page say user_details.php
use the header inorder to redirect
(e.g)

```
header("location:user_details.php");  //make sure this is placed before your html codes in case using in some other page
```

then use your session created to gather user details and display them in this page

hope this helps you, comment for any questions regarding this.

Comment: please see my updated code_exec.php file

Comment: is your insertion into the database working properly??

Comment: yes, it stores in database also.

Comment: check if session is created using print_r($_SESSION);